# What should I be looking for in a low cost color correcting monitor?

Tags: monitors, color-correction

I am in the market for a low-cost, color-correcting monitor. Please help me define "low cost." I don't want to skimp out but don't want to buy top dollar either. I know good monitors cost money.

I will be using the monitor for both Video and Photography. What features/specs should I consider a "bare minimum" so, hopefully, I wont need to buy two.

Comment: [Shopping recommendations are generally off-topic](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-do-you-think-about-shopping-recommendations), especially non-specific ones.

Comment: @Dave: We don't really allow "shopping recommendation" questions on this site, but I edited your question so you can get some of the information you need to get you started.

Comment: In terms of photography - this is a good read http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-monitor-for-photo-processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a loose binning of monitors into 3 categories:

1. Consumer equipment [$500 - $1500] Dell U-Series LCDs, Panasonic Viera Plasmas
2. Entry-Level Monitors [$2500+] FSI, HP DreamColor
3. High End Monitors [$$ - $$$$] eCinema, TV Logic

Some of the features of non-consumer monitors that you'll want to learn about are:

- HD/SDI inputs
- Additional outputs
- Colorspace and signal type support, such as 4:2:2
- "Higher" bit depth, such as 10-bit
- LUT programmability

If you're asking for low-cost, without already knowing these monitors, then I **strongly** suggest you stick to the first category, and use something like the DataColor Spyder calibration puck.  Getting that top 5% of color accuracy comes at a steep price, and since it seems you're just starting out, you probably want to stick with the 95% solution.  Upgrade only when you have specific need for the features.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Matrox MXO2 products. The Mini model allows you to gain blue gun control of a normal consumer HDTV, solving the big issue with calibration of these large displays. The MXO2 Mini is under $500, other models include features like hardware H.264 encoding and more advanced interfaces.