# How to buy a decent monitor

Tags: monitors

If I want good color rendition, do I just need to search for monitors with "IPS", high contrast, and high brightness?  Or are there other keywords I should use in shopping?

Note: I'm talking about CONSUMER monitors ($200-300 range), NOT fancy commercial models designed for ultra-accurate color.

Comment: Relevant: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/what-should-i-be-looking-for-in-a-low-cost-color-correcting-monitor

Comment: Additionally, try them!  Get a demo of any monitors you plan to use.

Comment: In addition to the content in the post I linked to, note that high contrast and high brightness isn't necessarily a strength when looking for color accuracy, but IPS and true 8bit or higher color is normally a good sign.  Many high contrast monitors use tricks of dimming portions of the screen to make the contrast ratio higher, but it destroys the ability to produce accurate color.